# При парсинге file_get_contents или curl_setopt не принимают ссылку из массива

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день.
Возникла такая проблема: при парсинге file_get_contents или curl_setopt не принимают ссылку из массивa, в файле много ссылок, если написать вот так(3 строчка):

```
$data = file('data.txt');
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://сайт/каталог/еще_что-нибудь.ру');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

то все работает, а если вот так, к примеру или через цикл:

```
$data = file('data.txt');
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $data[1]);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

то нет, ссылки абсолютно одинаковые, пробовал еще вот так:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'protocol_version' => '1.1',
        'header' => [
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
            'Connection: close',
        ],
    ]
]);
$stream = fopen('http://url', 'r', false, $context);
$content =  stream_get_contents($stream);
$data = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
```

то же самое, вручную набранная ссылка работает, из массива - нет.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Делайте так `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, trim($data[1]));`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Замечание:
Каждая строка в полученном массиве будет завершаться символами конца строки (если вы не указали флаг FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), поэтому, если вам будет нужно избавиться от этих символов, вы можете использовать функцию rtrim().
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php

Comment: Спасибо, получилось и так и как выше